# Like query with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

While doing this query i got

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Dentist' to data type int.

how to fix this ???

```
select * from tblBusinessCategory as b
inner join tblUser as u
on b.BusinessID=u.BusinessCategoryId
inner join tblAddress as a
on u.AddressId=a.AddressID
where u.BusinessCategoryId in (select BusinessCategory from tblBusinessCategory where BusinessCategory LIKE '%d%')
```

Comment: because you essentially comare BusinessCategoryId with BusinessCategory that obviously have different types

Comment: sql server not mysql, correct ?

Comment: sql server andrey sir.. i got answer sir. but How to perform like operation on multiple columns??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

You are selecting `BusinessCategory` in the subquery, which is varchar. And it is failed while trying to convert `BusinessCategory` to a type int.

**Solution:**

You should select `BusinessCategoryId` from table `tblBusinessCategory`:

```
............
where u.BusinessCategoryId in (select BusinessCategoryId from tblBusinessCategory where BusinessCategory LIKE '%d%')
```

**EDIT:**

To perform like operation on multiple columns, you can do this:

```
where u.BusinessCategoryId in 
   (select BusinessCategoryId 
    from tblBusinessCategory 
    where BusinessCategory LIKE '%d%' 
       or BusinessName LIKE '%something%'
       or BusinessDescription like '%something%')
```

Comment: Thnks Bull sir.. but How to perform like operation on multiple columns??

Comment: @AzkarRiyaz: What you mean by multiple columns? Can you please explain?

Comment: [BusinessName] like '%{0}%' or [BusinessCategory] like '%{0}%' or [BusinessDescription] like '%{0}%'  can i do like this sir ?

Comment: @AzkarRiyaz: Edited my answer to more simple method

Comment: @AzkarRiyaz: Yes, ofcourse. This has nothing to do with programming side, except receiving the dataset.

Comment: sorry sir network issue here.. so only that happens on un ticked

Comment: could u help on mvc ??

Comment: actual am fresher in I.T .. am dead in coding :(

Comment: @AzkarRiyaz: I am sorry to say I am not used to MVC. But, you can ask another question regarding MVC. There are so many users ready to help you at any time.

Comment: 90mins for next query thtz kills me alot :(

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your nested query:

```
in (select BusinessCategory from tblBusinessCategory where BusinessCategory LIKE '%d%')
```

should be

```
in (select BusinessCategoryId from tblBusinessCategory where BusinessCategory LIKE '%d%')
```